# How can I see if array is empty in multiple file upload PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

With a php multiple upload script, how can I check if the array is empty?
 
**Does not work:**

- `if(empty($_FILES['images']['name']))`
- `if($_FILES['images']['name'] === 'Array')`
- Using a for loop as the first check seems dirty.  Then I have a nested if statement in that first for loop. Then I have another for loop inside that one for the additional error checking.

What's the best way to do this? This doesn't see if the array is empty.  The first check only checks if the count($images) > 5.

```
// Begin image validation
                        if(isset($name)) { // here I want to see if image array is empty

                            // 5 max images allowed
                            if(count($name) > 5) {
                                ?>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += 'Max allowed images is 5';
                                </script>
                                <?php
                                } else {

                                    // Begin for loop
```

Comment: Please, improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of successfully uploaded files and number attempted:

```
<?php

$successfully_uploaded_files = 0;
$attempted_files = 0;

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
  if ($file['error'] === 0) {
    $successfully_uploaded_files++;
    $attempted_files++;
  } elseif ($file['error'] !== 4) {
    $attempted_files++;
  }
}
```

You should handle the other error codes appropriately:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php